# How to create a pull request in another account GitHub

Tags: git, github

I created a new Flutter project in Android Studio. I work on it and write code.

**Now I want to send a pull request to my friend's existing git project**. His & my git accounts are different. And I have no credentials for my friend's account. What is the way?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: why did you not just do everything in their repo, or make a shared repo

Answer (score 1):

First, your friend will need to add you as a collaborator on his repository. He can do this by going into the repository settings and inviting you as a collaborator by your username. Then you have to accept an email invitation. Then you will have push access to their repository from your account. Then you must fork their project repository to create a copy of it in your own account. Then clone this forked repository to your machine. Then you can push the changes to your forked repository. Then open up a pull request on Github from your fork to your friend's original repository.

Kindly, refer to [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo) for more details.

Comment: @MasrafiAtb. Kindly, press the green tick as well, that is located on my left side of my answer.